# XPATH in selenium Zillow schools

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Trying to create a program that web scrapes Zillow for the schools in a certain neighborhood but I am having some trouble scraping the xpath for the school information (rating, school name, and the grade)

I am having no luck grabbing the rating: 4/10 and the school name, see picture:

I have tried for the '4':
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="sc-1ra75gx-0 eYkapv"]/span[@class="Text-aiai24-0 egyxfz"]').text)` and it fails (outputs nothing). I tried to get the name of the school, in this case Del Roble Elementary School and it also is not returning the correct output. 
`(driver.find_element_by_xpath('(.//div[@class="sc-1ra75gx-3 fnKRzv"]/span[@class="ds-school-name ds-standard-label notranslate"])[1]').text)` and it doesnt output anything.

[image]

When I try to scrape for the grades of the particular school I use:

`(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='Text-aiai24-0 Qookr']").text)`
but it returns "Estimated Monthly Income" and my guess is because it uses the same span class so how can I grab grades and not the other one.

[image]

I am trying to get the output as the following:

```
School: Del Roble Elementary School
Rating: 4/10
Grade: K-6
```

Using mac os and firefox as my driver.
URL: https://www.zillow.com/san-jose-ca/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-121.87871932983398%2C%22east%22%3A-121.77486419677734%2C%22south%22%3A37.20517535620264%2C%22north%22%3A37.306966010798114%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A33839%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A13%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D

```
# IT WORKS
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# Open the browser and URL
h_count = 3
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
#url ="https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/33839_rid/2-_beds/84000-1979000_price/X1-SSg18dep4cy1ee1000000000_1y8ew_sse/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-121.96676450598144%2C%22east%22%3A-121.75905423986816%2C%22south%22%3A37.25989406246074%2C%22north%22%3A37.36706818940328%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A33839%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A12%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22price%22%3A%7B%22min%22%3A84000%2C%22max%22%3A1979000%7D%2C%22beds%22%3A%7B%22min%22%3A2%7D%2C%22sort%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22globalrelevanceex%22%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D"
url = "https://www.zillow.com/san-jose-ca/schools/"

driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//header[@class="school-name"]/@href[1]')
#rate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="zsg-media-img_ext school-card-rating"]/div')
info = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="school-fact school-grade"][1]')

print("name: " + str(name))
print("rating: " + str(rate))
print("info: " + str(info))
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the exact page you're trying to scrape?

Comment: Yes sorry, I added it to the original post. It's any of the listings on there

Comment: I wasn't able to see the same school format you posted a screenshot of, but I was able to go to the source of the data here: https://www.greatschools.org/california/schools/?gradeLevels%5B%5D=e&view=table You may have better luck attempting to parse the data there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably start here to scrape the schools of interest :

```
https://www.zillow.com/san-jose-ca/schools/#/san-jose-ca/schools
```

The `Del Roble Elementary School` appears on page 8.

To scrape the name of the school, the rating of the school and the grade from the list of results, you can use the following XPath :

```
//header[@class="school-name"]/a
//li//div[contains(@class,"gs-rating")]
//li[@class="school-card-info-item"][1]
```

The result of the last expression will need a bit of cleaning (removing the first part of "XXXX • Grades..."). Something like `result.partition("• ")[2]`

Or, assuming you build a list of schools from the list of results with `//header[@class="school-name"]//@href`, you can process each page with :

```
//h1
//div[@class="zsg-media-img_ext school-card-rating"]/div
//span[@class="school-fact school-grade"]
```

Output for [Del Roble](https://www.zillow.com/san-jose-ca/schools/del-roble-elementary-school-685/) : `Del Roble, 4, Grades-K6`

To be complete, you can also download directly the data in JSON format (200 schools per JSON). To build the correct request URL and assuming you've searched for "San Jose" (https://www.zillow.com/san-jose-ca/schools/) :

Look for the following element :

```
//div[@class="zsg-layout-width zsg-layout-top"]/div[1]
```

Get the attributes `@data-id` (id for the city) and `@data-mbr`(coordinates position). For `data-mbr`, you have to remove the `( )`.

With San Jose you'll find `33839` and `-122.045672,37.147971,-121.704359,37.469538`

You can build the url to fetch the JSON as follow :

```
https://www.zillow.com/ajax/schools.json?bb=value.of.data.mbr&sort=gs_rating&dir=desc&r=value.of.data.id
```

Add `&page=XX` if the number of results exceeds 200 (this can be found in the following element `//section[@class="school-region-about zsg-content-section"]//p`).

JSON urls for San Jose :

- https://www.zillow.com/ajax/schools.json?bb=-122.045672,37.147971,-121.704359,37.469538&sort=gs_rating&dir=desc&r=33839
- https://www.zillow.com/ajax/schools.json?bb=-122.045672,37.147971,-121.704359,37.469538&sort=gs_rating&dir=desc&r=33839&page=2

Use `import json`, `json.load` to filter the data afterwards.

Output :
[image: JSON]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your detailed answer. Unfortunately, I tried doing the following and it gave me some errors, I tried playing around with the xpath and still no luck. Can you recommend what I am doing wrong. See code below:    
/n
`name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//header[@class="school-name"]/@href[1]')`
`name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//header[@class="school-name"]/a[@href]')`
`rate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="zsg-media-img_ext school-card-rating"]/div')`
`info = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="school-fact school-grade"][1]')`

Comment: With which type of webpages are you working with ? The results from the search engine or the pages of each school ? `/header[@class="school-name"]//@href` is used to grab the urls of each school displayed in the search results. It might be better to grab the JSON data for your project. Add more details to your post, and provide a piece of your code if you want to get further assistance.

Comment: I have added my code and I was using the zillow main school site that you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Bad news. Scraping Zillow is against their TOS. Furthermore they use reCaptcha to prevent webscraping. That's why you get no results when Selenium downloads the page. Additional details can be found here : https://github.com/ChrisMuir/Zillow. Scrapehero offers a piece of code to scrape Zillow. You can read the users comments to fix and adapt it for your project (the  request part especially with the headers). Selenium won't be required . But I repeat, that's against Zillow TOS. Maybe you should try to fetch the data from "greatschools" as suggested by @scilence.